# Form is not being set to $dirty even though input is being edited

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am using angular-unsaved Changes directive as well as the angular built in form controller to detect if a form is `$dirty`.

I have a form on a specific page that even though I edit elements, the form never registers as dirty. I have gone so far as to strip everything and leave only:

```
<form unsaved-warning-form class="form-horizontal" name="WHAT">

        <input type="text" name="thematif" id="thematiff" class="form-control" >


    </form>
```

The `form`is never $dirty even when I change the value of the input. Any ideas what the problem could be causing the changes to `input` not to be detected? Is it that there should be an `angular` input equivalent tag instead of a plain old "input"?

What could be disabling the detection?

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Comment: @ Anik Islam Abhi Not really since I'd have to give the whole project and it is proprietary. The issue is that that form should be working.... what could be ways that the pristine/dirty functionality could be breaking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ng-model is missing on your input field.

Validations and all form enhancements are provided by utilizing ng-model directive (and its controller). So add ng-model and everything is Ok.

See: http://jsbin.com/podepo/edit?html,output

```
<form unsaved-warning-form class="form-horizontal" name="WHAT">
    <input type="text" name="thematif" ng-model="whatever" >

    <pre>{{WHAT|json}}</pre>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot... this was exactly the problem!!